# sql concat when original field is empty

Tags: sql, concatenation

I'm trying to run CONCAT on a column with fields that may or may not be empty. If the field isn't empty, there is no problem, i.e. if field in coulmn A equals a:

```
SET A = CONCAT(A, '_b')
```

gives a_b. The problem is, if the field in column A is empty, the concat returns nothing. Is there a way for it to concatenate even if the field is empty, which, in this example, would return '_b'?

Comment: Which RDMS are you asking about?  Most have a function to convert Null to a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sql server

```
SET A = CONCAT(isnull(A,''), '_b')
```

Use `IFNULL` in Mysql.

[Refer different function as per different database](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

Comment: fastest response ever! Thanks!

Comment: Minor nitpick: Although they have `isNull`, I don't think either Microsoft or Sybase SQL Server ever supported a `CONCAT` function for string concatenation. Rather they provide '+' in string expressions as the concatentation operator.  Oracle does have the `CONCAT` function for this (limited to two arguments, but you can nest multiple uses of it), but not `isNull`.  Instead Oracle gives us the `NVL` function for replacing Null values, as noted at your linked-to w3schools page.